# Button command binding doesn't work in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, xamarin.forms

I'd like to bind a command to the command property of my button. This seemed pretty straightforward since I've done this many times before in WPF and the method here is very similar. Let me show some code snippets.

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         x:Class="MyApp.View.CustomPage"
         Title="Something">

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button x:Name="numBtn" Text="Increase number" Command="{Binding IncreaseCommand}" />
        <Label x:Name="numLabel" Text="{Binding numberText}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code-behind**

```
public partial class CustomPage : ContentPage
{   
    public CustomPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = ViewModelLocator.ViewModel();  //ViewModelLocator is singleton, gives
                                                        //you a ViewModel instance
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public ICommand IncreaseCommand { get; private set; }
private int number;
public string numberText { get; private set;}
```

the constructor:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    IncreaseCommand = new Command (() => IncreaseExecuted ());
    number = 0;
    numberText = number.ToString ();
    OnPropertyChanged (numberText);
}
```

and then

```
private void IncreaseExecuted()
{
    number++;
    numberText = number.ToString ();
    OnPropertyChanged (numberText);
}
```

When I run the app using the Xamarin Android Player (KitKat) I see the button, and the label reading 0. Then I press the button and nothing happens. I tried checking what happens with breakpoints but the app doesn't pause, not even when they're in the constructor of my ViewModel. I guess it's something to do with the emulator. Anyway, I think the binding is ok since I can see a "0" on the screen. What could be the problem? Let me show my ViewModelBase class just in case:

**ViewModelBase**

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe my `numberText` property doesn't get updated when I call `OnPropertyChanged`? But I've used the exact same ViewModelBase class several times before and it always worked fine. One last thing, my `CustomPage` page is wrapped inside a `NavigationPage` which is a child of a `TabbedPage`:

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
this.Children.Add (new NavigationPage (new CustomPage ()) {Title="Something"} );
```

This shouldn't affect anything but there it is just in case. So what's wrong with my command binding? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are almost there. Take a close look at your call to the OnPropertyChanged method; you are passing the value of numberText and not the name. If you change your code to pass "numberText" I expect it shall work properly.

Edit: I should add that the the OnPropertyChanged call in the constructor has the same problem. The reason you see "0" at startup is that the view is simply using the existing binding to retrieve the value.

Edit 2: Now that Xamarin supports C# 6.0, you can use the new "nameof" expression that eliminates the need for a hard-coded string. Alternately, you can use MvvmCross, MvvmLight, or XLabs' MVVM classes.

Comment: You seem to be my savior these days! My second question in a row answered by you. Thank you so much! This was a rookie mistake, I don't know how I could be so stupid.

Comment: It's very common databinding issue. Since PropertyChangedEventArgs takes a string, it's VERY easy to mess up. Name changes due to refactoring are where I see it most often. To that end, I recommend using an implementation of a ViewModelBase that takes an expression as input instead of a string and will therefore cause build errors if the property name is changed without also updating the event firing code. MvvmLight and MvvmCross both supply this.

Comment: I see. Good idea, I'm gonna implement this. Thank you!

Comment: sometimes... we should care about little and minor things.

Answer (score 14):

This answer is not directly related to the problem of the original question, however this question is the one that ranks highest in search engines and the title of this question is ambiguous to the question that this answer answers.

I was having issues with a `Command` that wouldn't fire the associated command action. My problem was that I had defined the `Command` as a `field` instead of a `property`.

Works:

```
public Command MyCommand { get; set; }
```

Doesn't work:

```
public Command MyCommand;
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks, that saved me. In my case intelliSense did still show MyCommand as an option to bind although i was mistakenly using a field. Is there a reason for this? I thought data binding to fields is not even possible. (I did not get any errors, but the command was not triggered)

Comment: @Hannes I'm not sure what the underlying reason is to be honest. I just made this answer to save myself (and others) in the future when I get this issue again and try to Google it. ‍♂️